# Using bootstrap 4 with Vaadin 14

Tags: bootstrap-4, vaadin

I try to use the bootstrap styles, and tried to include them in MainView as @StyleSheet with an URL given,

```
@StyleSheet("https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css")
```

or as @CssImport referencing to a local copy,

```
@CssImport("./src/css/bootstrap.min.css")
```

but both are not interpreted.
Any ideas, what I'm missing?
Thanks!

EDITED: my trials don't seem to work with PolymerTemplates due to the shadow DOM. If I include a copy of the `bootstrap.min.css` file (manually of the content of the file) directly into the `<style>`-annotation of the template in the `main-view`, I have all styles available. This is a workaround for now. I would prefer not to need to copy content and reference the bootstrap file directly. Please let me know if you have any ideas! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: found [here](https://javascript.info/shadow-dom-style): Shadow DOM may include both `<style>` and `<link rel="stylesheet" href="…">` tags. :)